# Populating a PostgreSQL table with sample data using summary stats

Tags: sql, postgresql, sample

My customer has a table with ~150 columns in their DB. I don't have access to the DB, I only have summary stats about each column in the table - distinct values in each column along with their likelihood of occurrence.

I'm trying to create a representative copy of this table on my own DB so that I can run queries against it for testing purposes. The only way I know to do this is to write a huge SELECT statement that uses the `random()` function to randomly choose between the possible values of each column (and other methods for timestamps and IDs). This SELECT is then used inside an INSERT INTO.

This approach just isn't scalable though. I want to be able to do this for a lot more tables. Is there an easier way to do this? I'd like to avoid paid tools if possible.

Comment: Insert distinct values in one table and number of occurrences in other tables and do a cross join.   If you have access to aggregated data why the customer is not giving access to the full table. This is very strange scenario

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  This should be quite feasible using SQL, but without knowing how many values are in the largest columns and what the structure of the tables are, it is hard to make suggestions.